# Transitivity of $\Omega$ in subspace actions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, simple-groups, classical-groups

Let $G=O(V, Q)$ be a finite orthogonal group acting naturally on a space $V\cong \mathbb{F}_q^n$ equipped with a quadratic form $Q$. Assume $n=\dim V\geq c$ for some large enough constant $c$ in order to get rid of small exceptional examples. Let $W\subseteq V$ be a subspace of dimension $m$ that is either totally singular or nondegenerate ($W$ can also be a nonsingular 1-space when $q$ is even). Let $S$ be the set of subspaces $W'\subseteq V$ isometric to $W$ with respect to $Q$, i.e., $W'$ admits a invertible linear map $\sigma: W\to W'$ such that $Q(\sigma(x))=Q(x)$ for $x\in W$. Then $G$ acts on $S$ by permuting the subspaces. By Witt's lemma, this action is transitive.
The stabilizers $G_{W'}$ for $W'\in S$ belong to *Aschbacher's class $\mathcal{C}_1$* introduced in
[Michael Aschbacher: On the maximal subgroups of the finite classical groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388470).

Let $\Omega$ be the normal subgroup of $SO(V, Q)\leq G$ of index two. I am curious about whether $\Omega$ acts transitively on $S$.

In the case that $V$ is hyperbolic and $W$ is totally singular of dimension $m=n/2$, it is known that $\Omega$ is intransitive: it has two orbits distinguished by the parity of $\dim W'\cap W$. Is this the only exception? If so, how to see it? Thanks.

I am reading the book *The Subgroup Structure of the Finite Classical Groups* by Peter B. Kleidman and Martin W. Liebeck, and the tables there seem to suggest the above exception is the only one. But I am not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe that you are correct in saying that  the case you describe is the only exception.

By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, the transitivity of the action of $\Omega$ on $S$ is equivalent to the stabilizer of $W$ including elements in each of the cosets of $\Omega$ in $G$. (There are two such cosets when $q$ is even and four when $q$ is odd). This information can be read off from the tables in the book by Kleidman and Liebeck.

Looking at the subgroups in class $\mathcal{C}_1$ Tables 3.5.D, 3.5.E and 3.5.F, we see that $\pi = 1$ in most cases, in which case the $\Omega$-conjugacy class of $S$ is also a conjugacy class of the full conformal orthogonal group, and so the action of $\Omega$ on $S$ is transitive in these cases.

Otherwise, we have $\pi=\pi_1$ or $\pi_2$, and there are two $\Omega$-classes that are fused under the conformal group (i.e. $c=2$ in the notation of the book).

The case when it is $\pi_2$ is the exceptional case when $\Omega$ is not transitive on $S$. In this case, the two $\Omega$-orbits are interchanged by the outer automorphism of $\Omega$ that is denoted by $\gamma$ (possibly with two dots on it - I find all these dots confusing).

In the case $\pi=\pi_1$, that the stabilizer of the $\Omega$-class is the kernel of the map $\tau$ with two dots on it. This map is defined at the end of Section 2.1 on page 20, and this kernel is equal to the orthogonal group $\Omega$, which has index two in the conformal orthogonal group, so the action of $\Omega$ on $S$ is transitive in that case.

As for how to see all of this, I am afraid I do not know any way other than reading the proofs in the book.